# jQuery Click button and get the nearest id above:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html and when I click on the button I need to get the nearest id on the wrapper div above

Here is the html:

```
<div id="some_id_here" class="wrapper>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="toolbuttons">
        <a class="btn btn-default">click here and get the id in wrapper</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Read: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#targetText=Event%20delegation%20refers%20to%20the,now%20or%20in%20the%20future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `closest` with class selector and read id using `attr`

```js
$(function(){
   $('a.btn').on('click', function(){
      var id = $(this).closest('.wrapper').attr('id');
      console.log(id);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_id_here" class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="toolbuttons">
        <a class="btn btn-default">click here and get the id in wrapper</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('a.btn').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest("[id]").attr("id");
  console.log(id)
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('a.btn').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest("[id]").attr("id");
  console.log(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_id_here" class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="toolbuttons">
        <a class="btn btn-default">click here and get the id in wrapper</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="some_id_here" class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="tester">
      <div class="toolbuttons">
        <a class="btn btn-default">click here and get the id in panel-heading</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
 let wrapperid = $(this).closest('.wrapper').prop('id')
 console.log(wrapperid)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_id_here" class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="toolbuttons">
        <a class="btn btn-default">click here and get the id in wrapper</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var newid = $(this).closest('div[id]');
$(this).att('id', $newid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although all answer is correct but you can use **parents** method with **class selector** to find that div. below is working code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn").on("click",function(){
        console.log($(this).parents('.wrapper').attr("id"));
     })
 });
```

here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/2dk5terz/17/)

Answer (score 0):

To find the nearest parent with id using JS.

```js
function foo(ele) {
  var id = ele.closest("[id]").id;
  console.log(id)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_id_here" class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="toolbuttons">
        <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="foo(this)">click here and get the id in wrapper</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> $('btn-default').click(function() {
>      var id = $(this).closest(".wrapper").attr("id");
>      console.log(id) 
>   });